# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "130625143100"

Tags: java, date, exception, format

this is my code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss");
    Date date = sdf.parse("130625143100");
```

i have a long list of date strings, all in the same format as above one,
wierd thing is some success, some fail.

can any one help out with WHY this happens.

thanks a lot.

Comment: There's no problem with that code: `Tue Jun 25 14:31:00 CEST 2013`

Comment: I can't see any issue here

Comment: Can you provide an example which fails?

Comment: What does “fail” mean？  Is it exception or just parse to error date?

Comment: If it is just parse to error date, you may try sdf.setLient(false); So when you try to parse like("130025143100"),this will throw Exception

Answer (score 1):

You said, some string parses well while some string fails. Put your code in trycatch block. Log the string for which it is failing. The string may not be as per the format you specified in SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss");
    Date date = sdf.parse("130625143100");
```

mistake in doblue quote

Comment: is there any thing new here? Same thing in question

Comment: when i show question new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss"); printed as new SimpleDateFormat(""yyMMddHHmmss);

Comment: I edited the question, but still it would not throw the exception OP is talking about, it would simply not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to validate your strings, for example if the value of month is greater than 12 then it will fail or for similar reasons.